# Extremely hard problem with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with this problem. If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that

$$|a-1|+|a-2|+|a-3|+\cdots+|a-2015|=b(b+1)$$

find the sum $a+b$.

Comment: similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077111/equation-with-absolute-values-and-parameters/1077162#1077162) ?

Comment: no, this another one

Comment: But it does look very similar, doesn't it? Have you tried applying what was posted in answer to that earlier question?

Comment: Yes, but the answer to this question is 2015.

Comment: Not if $a\geq 2015$ is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

if $f(x) = |x-1| +|x-2| +\cdots+|x-2015|,$ then 
$\begin{align}
f(1008) &=1007 + 1006 + \cdots 2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + \cdots + 1006 + 1007\\
& = 2 \dfrac{(1+1007)}{2} 1007 \\
& = 1008*1007
\end{align}$

therefore $$ a = 1008, b = 1007, a+b = 2015$$

this is the only solution as the graph of $y = f(x)$ is made up of line segments symmetric about $x = 1008$ and can only cut $y =x^2 + x$ at two points.